# Database schema - Set Limit values in correlation to groups and it's members

Tags: sql, vba, database, algorithm, ms-access

Provided there are pre-existing tables (diagram attached below). They each have numerous use-case as far as potentially related attributes. Still, I am at a roadblock following best practices with confidence, trying to add a specific piece of functionality that we can call *Limit* with its respected table and associated attributes, which will have more than just an int value.

**Pre-existing tables (reduced to relevant attributes):**

[image: Pre-existing tables]

**Limit Table:**

[image: Limit Table Diagram]

The problem is, I want to be able to apply a "Limit" value to both, Tasks and Groups, but find it hard to choose between the following approaches I have come up with due to the pros and cons and what could be considered best practice.

**Approach 1:**

[image: ERD Approach 1]

*In the Limit table, add two foreign keys attributes (task_id, group_id) to each tuple (row)*

**Approach 2:**

[image: ERD Approach 2]

*In the Limit table, add one foreign key attribute (taskgroup_id) with a "toggle" attribute (is_group) to each tuple (row)*

**Thoughts:**

Naturally, I think the second can be considered better practice because it reduces the number of NULL values being inserted into the database, and therefore, is more along the lines of a relational database structure.

To make functionality brief, each Task should be assigned a Limit Value, but if no Limit tuple/row is inserted for a Task with a Limit Value, we should refer to the Task’s respected Group for the Limit Value (one Group is linked to all Tasks).

**Edit:**

Which would be a better approach, or is there a better approach than the two provided?

Please advise if I should elaborate somewhere.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Based on the approaches I have listed, which would be better as far as best practice, or is there an approach better than the two provided?

Comment: You may want to try the [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site . This question seems a bit too opinion based for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this approach:

[image: Relationship]

When your entry does not have a group or a task, you can enter `0` in the `TaskGroups` table, which (the 0) should be `Not Task` in the Tasks table and `Not Group` in the Groups table.